# PLinq parallel summing performance inconsistency

Tags: c#, .net, linq, task-parallel-library, plinq

I have the following code to test how much faster PLinq could sum up numbers than Linq could do:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static readonly IEnumerable<Company> _smallCompanies = GenerateSmallCompanies();

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("just decimals");
        var numbers=Enumerable.Range (0, 10000000).Select(n=>(decimal)n).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine ("one thread");
            Timer (()=>numbers.Aggregate((a,b)=>a+b));
            Console.WriteLine ("plinq many threads");
            Timer (()=>numbers.AsParallel().Aggregate(decimal.Zero,(a,b)=>a+b,(r1,r2)=>r1+r2,f=>f));    
        }

        Console.WriteLine ("decimals in wrapper objects");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            WithWrappers ();
        }
    }

    private static void Timer(Action act){
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        act ();
        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine( " Time: " +
            stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    private static void WithWrappers()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("==========================");

        PrintMergeResult(LinearMerger.LinearMerge, "one thread");
        PrintMergeResult(FunctionalParallelMerger.FunctionalParallelMerge, "plinq many threads");
    }

    private static void PrintMergeResult(Func<Company, IEnumerable<Company>, Company> mergeMethod,
        string funcApproach)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(funcApproach);
        Timer (() => mergeMethod (new Company { EvaluatedMarketValue = 0 }, _smallCompanies));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Company> GenerateSmallCompanies()
    {
        return Enumerable
            .Range(0, 10000000)
            .Select(number => new Company {EvaluatedMarketValue = number});
    }
}

internal class Company
{
    public decimal EvaluatedMarketValue { get; set; }

    public Company Merge(Company that)
    {
        EvaluatedMarketValue += that.EvaluatedMarketValue;
        return this;
    }
}

internal class FunctionalParallelMerger
{
    public static Company FunctionalParallelMerge(Company bigCompany, IEnumerable<Company> smallCompanies)
    {
        return smallCompanies
            .AsParallel()
            .Aggregate(CreateShell,
                (shell, smallCompany) => shell.Merge(smallCompany),
                (shell1, shell2) => shell1.Merge(shell2),
                bigCompany.Merge);
    }

    private static Company CreateShell()
    {
        return new Company();
    }
}

internal class LinearMerger
{
    public static Company LinearMerge(Company bigCompany, IEnumerable<Company> smallCompanies)
    {
        foreach (var smallCompany in smallCompanies)
        {
            bigCompany.Merge(smallCompany);
        }
        return bigCompany;
    }
}
```

The result is not as expected, when it's just decimal numbers, PLinq is faster, but when the numbers are wrapped in small Company objects, PLinq is slower, here is the log:

```
just decimals
one thread
 Time: 562
plinq many threads
 Time: 525
one thread
 Time: 569
plinq many threads
 Time: 460
one thread
 Time: 573
plinq many threads
 Time: 283
one thread
 Time: 570
plinq many threads
 Time: 193
one thread
 Time: 548
plinq many threads
 Time: 194
one thread
 Time: 525
plinq many threads
 Time: 174
one thread
 Time: 524
plinq many threads
 Time: 137
one thread
 Time: 555
plinq many threads
 Time: 153
one thread
 Time: 535
plinq many threads
 Time: 145
one thread
 Time: 554
plinq many threads
 Time: 159
decimals in wrapper objects
==========================
one thread
 Time: 762
plinq many threads
 Time: 2880
==========================
one thread
 Time: 719
plinq many threads
 Time: 2915
==========================
one thread
 Time: 686
plinq many threads
 Time: 2924
==========================
one thread
 Time: 690
plinq many threads
 Time: 2919
==========================
one thread
 Time: 697
plinq many threads
 Time: 2928
==========================
one thread
 Time: 710
plinq many threads
 Time: 2984
==========================
one thread
 Time: 700
plinq many threads
 Time: 2986
==========================
one thread
 Time: 723
plinq many threads
 Time: 3054
==========================
one thread
 Time: 779
plinq many threads
 Time: 3030
==========================
one thread
 Time: 756
plinq many threads
 Time: 2901
```

What is the reason? Too many small objects? GC?

Comment: in my computer for `decimals in wrapper objects` gives me this results. `one thread 739` and `many threads 763`. but for `just decimals` i get same results as yours

Comment: You're comparing two quite different functions, `Aggregate` and simple `foreach`. `foreach` is nearly always faster when compared to LINQ. At least make a fair comparison.

Comment: @GertArnold No, I was comparing a simple foreach loop with PLinq, not with Linq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static IEnumerable<Company> GenerateSmallCompanies()
{
    return Enumerable
        .Range(0, 10000000)
        .Select(number => new Company {EvaluatedMarketValue = number});
}
```

Found the problem, it's this method.
Here it's doing lazy eval, add ToList, or ToArray at the end, Plinq will be much faster.